# Taking any no. of int inputs from user from [1-99] and giving output on how many single/double digits are there in shell

Tags: shell

Taking any no. of int inputs from user from [1-99] and giving output on how many single/double digits are there in shell

```
sample input:1,4,5,66,99,10,55
sample output:single digit no:3
              double digit no:4
```

what i have done so far

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "how many inputs do u wish to take"
u=0
v=0
read n

for ((i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++))
do
echo "enter inputs"
read x
while [ $x -le 99 && $x -ge 1 ]
do
if [ $x -le 9 ]
then
u=$((u + 1)) 
else
v=$((v + 1))

fi
done
done
echo "single digit numbers:" $u
echo "double digit numbers:" $v
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `while` (and its matching `do`, `done`) and it should do the trick.
alternatively, turn the `while` into an `if` if you want to sanitize the input. if you do, note that `&&` can't go into a `[ ... ]` condition, and replace it with `-a`